# Division of polynomials in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

If we had $f(x)=x^4+1$ and $g(x)=4x+1$ in $\Bbb Z_5$, I am curious how to divide $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ since the leading coefficient is not $1$. Would we have to multiply $g(x)$ by $4$'s inverse? Thanks!

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Or taking into account that $4\equiv -1\pmod 5$.

Comment: Then we would have -1(4k+1) = -4k-1 which in mod 5 is k+4 correct?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027960/irreducible-polynomials-in-qx-vs-zpx-for-prime-number-4k1) for a related question.